# How do I use the IComparable interface?

Tags: c#, .net, icomparable

I need a basic example of how to use the `IComparable` interface so that I can sort in ascending or descending order and by different fields of the object type I'm sorting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, since you are using `List<T>` it would be a lot simpler to just use a `Comparison<T>`, for example:

```
List<Foo> data = ...
// sort by name descending
data.Sort((x,y) => -x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

Of course, with LINQ you could just use:

```
var ordered = data.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Name);
```

But you can re-introduce this in `List<T>` (for in-place re-ordering) quite easily; Here's an example that allows `Sort` on `List<T>` with lambda syntax:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;  

class Foo { // formatted for vertical space
    public string Bar{get;set;}
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        List<Foo> data = new List<Foo> {
            new Foo {Bar = "abc"}, new Foo {Bar = "jkl"},
            new Foo {Bar = "def"}, new Foo {Bar = "ghi"}
        };
        data.SortDescending(x => x.Bar);
        foreach (var row in data) {
            Console.WriteLine(row.Bar);
        }
    }

    static void Sort<TSource, TValue>(this List<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
        var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
        source.Sort((x,y)=>comparer.Compare(selector(x),selector(y)));
    }
    static void SortDescending<TSource, TValue>(this List<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
        var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
        source.Sort((x,y)=>comparer.Compare(selector(y),selector(x)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer starts a bit confusing, it assumes that I've already read information that isn't in the question but in an answer posted by the OP.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple example:

```
public class SortableItem : IComparable<SortableItem>
{
    public int someNumber;

    #region IComparable<SortableItem> Members

    public int CompareTo(SortableItem other)
    {
        int ret = -1;
        if (someNumber < other.someNumber)
            ret = -1;
        else if (someNumber > other.someNumber)
            ret = 1;
        else if (someNumber == other.someNumber)
            ret = 0;
        return ret;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

*"That's great, but what if I want to be able to control the sort order, or sort by another field?"*

Simple. All we need to do is add few more fields to the object. First we'll add a string for a different sort type and then we'll add a boolean to denote whether we're sorting in descending or ascending order and then add a field which determines which field we want to search by.

```
public class SortableItem : IComparable<SortableItem>
{
    public enum SortFieldType { SortNumber, SortString }

    public int someNumber = -1;
    public string someString = "";
    public bool descending = true;    
    public SortFieldType sortField = SortableItem.SortFieldType.SortNumber;        

    #region IComparable<SortableItem> Members

    public int CompareTo(SortableItem other)
    {
        int ret = -1;
        if(sortField == SortableItem.SortFieldType.SortString)
        {
            // A lot of other objects implement IComparable as well.
            // Take advantage of this.
            ret = someString.CompareTo(other.someString);
        }
        else
        {
            if (someNumber < other.someNumber)
                ret = -1;
            else if (someNumber > other.someNumber)
                ret = 1;
            else if (someNumber == other.someNumber)
                ret = 0;
        }
        // A quick way to switch sort order:
        // -1 becomes 1, 1 becomes -1, 0 stays the same.
        if(!descending) ret = ret * -1; 

        return ret;
    }

    #endregion

    public override string ToString()
    {
       if(sortField == SortableItem.SortFieldType.SortString)
          return someString;
       else
          return someNumber.ToString();
    }
}
```

*"Show me how!"*

Well since you asked so nicely.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        List<SortableItem> items = new List<SortableItem>();
        SortableItem temp = new SortableItem();
        temp.someString = "Hello";
        temp.someNumber = 1;
        items.Add(temp);
        temp = new SortableItem();
        temp.someString = "World";
        temp.someNumber = 2;
        items.Add(temp);
        SortByString(items);
        Output(items);
        SortAscending(items);
        Output(items);
        SortByNumber(items);
        Output(items);
        SortDescending(items);
        Output(items);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void SortDescending(List<SortableItem> items)
    {
        foreach (SortableItem item in items)
            item.descending = true;
    }
    public static void SortAscending(List<SortableItem> items)
    {
        foreach (SortableItem item in items)
            item.descending = false;
    }
    public static void SortByNumber(List<SortableItem> items)
    {
        foreach (SortableItem item in items)
            item.sortField = SortableItem.SortFieldType.SortNumber;
    }
    public static void SortByString(List<SortableItem> items)
    {
        foreach (SortableItem item in items)
            item.sortField = SortableItem.SortFieldType.SortString;
    }
    public static void Output(List<SortableItem> items)
    {
        items.Sort();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Item " + i + ": " + items[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: That is actually pretty yeucky, sorry to say it. There are much better approaches, especially using LINQ or a LINQ-inspired approach...

Comment: There isn't anything that says you can't answer the question too if you have a better idea.

Comment: I have - I was just writing it ;-p

Answer (score 4):

If you want dynamic sort, you can use LINQ

```
var itemsOrderedByNumber = ( from item in GetClasses() orderby item.Number select item ).ToList();
var itemsOrderedByText = ( from item in GetClasses() orderby item.Text select item ).ToList();
var itemsOrderedByDate = ( from item in GetClasses() orderby item.Date select item ).ToList();
```

or "Sort" method of List class:

```
List<Class1> itemsOrderedByNumber2 = new List<Class1>( GetClasses() );
itemsOrderedByNumber2.Sort( ( a, b ) => Comparer<int>.Default.Compare( a.Number, b.Number ) );

List<Class1> itemsOrderedByText2 = new List<Class1>( GetClasses() );
itemsOrderedByText2.Sort( ( a, b ) => Comparer<string>.Default.Compare( a.Text, b.Text ) );

List<Class1> itemsOrderedByDate2 = new List<Class1>( GetClasses() );
itemsOrderedByDate2.Sort( ( a, b ) => Comparer<DateTime>.Default.Compare( a.Date, b.Date ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for sorting list

```
namespace GenaricClass
{
    class Employee :IComparable<Employee>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Salary { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Employee other)
        {
            if (this.Salary < other.Salary) return 1;
            else if (this.Salary > other.Salary) return -1;
            else return 0;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee{Name="a",Salary=140000},
                new Employee{Name="b",Salary=120000},
                new Employee{Name="c",Salary=160000},
                new Employee{Name="d",Salary=10000}
            };
            empList.Sort();
            foreach (Employee emp in empList)
            {
                System.Console.Write(emp.Salary +",");
            }
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be in relation to sorting order, but it is still - I think - an interesting use of `IComparable`:

```
public static void MustBeInRange<T>(this T x, T minimum, T maximum, string paramName)
where T : IComparable<T>
{
    bool underMinimum = (x.CompareTo(minimum) < 0);
    bool overMaximum = (x.CompareTo(maximum) > 0);
    if (underMinimum || overMaximum)
    {
        string message = string.Format(
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "Value outside of [{0},{1}] not allowed/expected",
            minimum, maximum
        );
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramName))
        {
            Exception noInner = null;
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(message, noInner);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, x, message);
        }
    }
}

public static void MustBeInRange<T>(this T x, T minimum, T maximum)
where T : IComparable<T> { x.MustBeInRange(minimum, maximum, null); }
```

These simple extension methods allow you to do parameter range checking for any type that implements `IComparable` like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(int percentage, string file) {
    percentage.MustBeInRange(0, 100, "percentage");
    file.MustBeInRange("file000", "file999", "file");
    // do something with percentage and file
    // (caller will have gotten ArgumentOutOfRangeExceptions when applicable)
}
```

Comment: To be honest, you're unlikely to use it on a type that isn't `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable`, so I'd drop the constraint and use Comparer<T>.Default. This is, for example, how LINQ-to-Objects does Min/Max.

Comment: Hadn't though of that. Thanks for the tip. However, wouldn't that show the extension method everything (=on types I'd be "unlikely to use it on") while with the type constraint it'll only show on types that actually are IComparable?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Sorting_ComplexTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer customer1 = new Customer {
                ID = 101,
                Name = "Mark",
                Salary = 2400,
                Type = "Retail Customers"
            };
            Customer customer2 = new Customer
            {
                ID = 102,
                Name = "Brian",
                Salary = 5000,
                Type = "Retail Customers"
            };
            Customer customer3 = new Customer
            {
                ID = 103,
                Name = "Steve",
                Salary = 3400,
                Type = "Retail Customers"
            };

            List<Customer> customer = new List<Customer>();
            customer.Add(customer1);
            customer.Add(customer2);
            customer.Add(customer3);

            Console.WriteLine("Before Sorting");
            foreach(Customer c in customer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
            }

            customer.Sort();
            Console.WriteLine("After Sorting");
            foreach(Customer c in customer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
            }

            customer.Reverse();
            Console.WriteLine("Reverse Sorting");
            foreach (Customer c in customer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
            }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Customer : IComparable<Customer>
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Customer other)
        {
            return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
        }
    }
```