# How to print sorted list?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to sort a list of cars by their price range. Currently I'm unsure if I've even sorted it correctly with IComparable, and I can't figure out how I print the list after it's sorted, I can only print them in the order they were declared.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Interface1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Car : IComparable<Car>
        {
            public string Make { get; set; }
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public double Price { get; set; }

            public int CompareTo(Car car)
            {
                return this.Price.CompareTo(car.Price);
            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                List<Car> cars = new List<Car>()
            {
                new Car(){Make = "Skoda", Model = "Fabia", Price = 50000},
                new Car(){Make = "Skoda", Model = "Octavia", Price = 60000},
                new Car(){Make = "Nissan", Model = "Juke", Price = 45000 }
            };

                foreach (var car in cars)
                    Console.WriteLine(car.Price);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have I done the sorting correctly? How can I print it properly?

Comment: And where you sorted the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the IComparable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435404/how-do-i-use-the-icomparable-interface)

Comment: You may want to look into the [SortedList class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.8). What you've used is just a plain list that doesn't do any sort automatically, even though you've correctly implemented `IComparable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line as so

```
foreach (var car in cars.OrderBy(x => x.Price))
                Console.WriteLine(car.Price);
```

You can add a different comparer as well in the `OrderBy` function.